# Can't create a remote admin using powershell

Tags: powershell

Good afternoon.
I would like to ask for help.
I am trying to execute a script remotely.
When doing this, I get a NULL password error.
Please tell me how to be.

```
$pcName = @("pc1","pc2")    

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName {$UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123456" -AsPlainText -Force}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName -ScriptBlock { New-LocalUser -Name "admintest" -Password $UserPassword -PasswordNeverExpires }

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName -ScriptBlock { Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrator" -Member "admintest" }
```

P.S I'm just learning.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the scriptblock, variable `$UserPassword` is unknown. To be able to use the variable in the scriptblock, you need to either scope it with `$using:UserPassword`:

```
$UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123456" -AsPlainText -Force
$pcName = "pc1", "pc2"  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName -ScriptBlock { 
    try {
        $newUser = New-LocalUser -Name "admintest" -Password $using:UserPassword -PasswordNeverExpires -ErrorAction Stop
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $newUser
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not create the new user:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

OR

Have the scriptblock accept parameter(s) in a `param(..)` block and call like

```
$UserPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "test123456" -AsPlainText -Force
$pcName = "pc1", "pc2"  
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $pcName -ScriptBlock { 
    param ( [securestring] $Password )
    try {
        $newUser = New-LocalUser -Name "admintest" -Password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires -ErrorAction Stop
        Add-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member $newUser
    }
    catch {
        Write-Warning "Could not create the new user:`r`n$($_.Exception.Message)"
    }
} -ArgumentList $UserPassword
```

P.S.

- The group is called `Administrators` (plural)
- I have used a `try{..} catch{..}` so you will receive an error message when things go wrong

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed.
They opened my eyes.